# minimal test with apache geode

Tags: c++, gemfire, geode

I would like to extend geode with custom binary data (serialization). Is there any documentation about how to kickoff a minimal setup/system using geode? I saw a [docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/apachegeode/geode/) but didn't find any docs on this.

It would be more than enough for me to have a c++ client which can push and query the stored (~30 GB of) data by a key.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index#Index-Geodein5minutes

There is more information on the Geode Wiki as well that maybe of use to you.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Application+Development

This maybe of particular interests to you...

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/PDX+Serialization+Internals

Hope this helps get you started.

Cheers!

Comment: are there examples in c++?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ and C# clients are currently not part of Apache Geode, just Pivotal GemFire.

You will find information about Geode and Docker [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/How+to+use+Geode+on+Docker), [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/apachegeode/geode/) and [here](https://github.com/markito/geode-docker).

Answer (score 0):

There may not be actual documentation for C++, but you can use the REST client to communication with GemFire as well. Documentation is [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/gemfire_rest/chapter_overview.html) and [here](http://geode-docs.cfapps.io/docs/geode_rest/chapter_overview.html).